# How to get CUSIP-Description data using Bloomberg API?

Tags: python, api, bloomberg

I had a look at [Asynchronous data through Bloomberg's new data API (COM v3) with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2005234/477256) before posting which has some pretty awesome info, but what I need is a way to create a CUSIP-Description table in a database using the Bloomberg API (to save $$$ by avoiding a CUSIP subscription)

Does anyone know how to populate a table with CUSIP and description using the Bloomberg API?

Comment: Bloomberg tend to crack down on you pretty quickly if you use the API to get data and avoid a subscription. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Oh no this would be using a Bloomberg terminal subscription. You can get your own CUSIP subscription separately but Bloomberg has all the info included. It just needs to be accessed. There is information for Excel(vb) but no other languages.

Comment: @signal you can download the data and use it on your terminal. But the minute you store it in a database, Bloomberg could argue that it is a breach of contract, especially if the database is located on a different machine.